# Убрать сервисный адрес сайта

Tags: vds

Здравствуйте. 
Сайт доступен как по основному домену, так и по сервисному домену  `ih4321452.vds.host.ru`
Подскажите, где в ispmanager это убирается ?
Нашел запись зоны SOA, именно там и прописан сервисный адрес, а вот как отредактировать не пойму !
Спасибо!

Comment: Если вы не владеете host.ru, то скорее всего никак

Comment: В настройках nginx или apache